# Getting a scheme macro keyword to match only if at least two arguments are given to it

Tags: macros, scheme, r5rs

I am trying to implement a keyword (named `=`) for a macro transformer (named `latex`) which is intended to match only if at least two arguments are given to it. My attempt is:

```lisp
     ((_ (= a b))
      `(,@(latex a) "=" ,@(latex b)))
     ((_ (= a b ...))
      `(,@(latex a) "=" ,@(latex (= b ...))))
```

but this implementation matches when only one argument is given to `=` and gives an undesirable result. A table of outputs for various inputs is given below.

| Input to [`latex`](https://gitlab.com/vyuh/symbolic-mathematics/-/blob/master/mac.scm#L22) | Displayed Result | comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| = | = | ok (no match) |
| (=) | (=) | ok (no match) |
| (= a) | a=(=) | *bad match*. result should be (= a) |
| (= a b) | a=b | ok (match) |
| (= a b c) | a=b=c | ok (match) |
| (= a b c d) | a=b=c=d | ok (match) |

You may view [the source file](https://gitlab.com/vyuh/symbolic-mathematics/-/blob/master/mac.scm#L164) or [the project page](https://gitlab.com/vyuh/symbolic-mathematics/) if you require more context.

Comment: Maybe use pattern `(_ (= a b c ...))` instead of `(_ (= a b ...))`? (c can have zero occurrences)

Comment: @mnemenaut thank you. This worked. If you post this as an answer with some relevant quote from https://schemers.org/Documents/Standards/R5RS/HTML/r5rs-Z-H-7.html#%_sec_4.3.2 I'll accept that.